# PySide QFileOpenDialog , dialog shows up under the jupyter browser

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have the following snippet in an in ipython/jupyter browser cell.
When I run this cell the first time, I have a PySide QT File dialog opening up properly
But when I run this cell the second time, the file dialog appears under the browser window.

-thanks in advance

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
def file_select(dir=None, dirSelect=False, parent=None):
    """
    Select a file via a dialog and return the file name.
    """
    if dir is None:
        dir = './'

    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    if not app:
        app = QtGui.QApplication([dir])

    retVal=None
    try:
        dlgTitle = 'Select Directory' if dirSelect else 'Select File'
        dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(parent, dlgTitle)
        if dirSelect:
            dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.Directory)
            dialog.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)

        if dialog.exec_():
            fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles()
            selected_file = fileNames[0]
            retVal = str(selected_file)
    finally:
        pass
    return retVal

file_select('./', dirSelect= True)
```

other details,

```
pip list
```

gives

```
backports-abc (0.4)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
certifi (2016.2.28)
cffi (1.6.0)
configparser (3.3.0.post2)
cryptography (1.3.2)
cycler (0.10.0)
decorator (4.0.9)
entrypoints (0.2.1)
enum34 (1.1.4)
filelock (2.0.6)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
futures (3.0.5)
h5py (2.6.0)
idna (2.1)
ipaddress (1.0.16)
ipykernel (4.3.1)
ipyparallel (5.0.1)
ipython (4.2.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (5.1.3)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (4.2.2)
jupyter-console (4.1.1)
jupyter-core (4.1.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
mistune (0.7.2)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
nbformat (4.0.1)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.0)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.2.0)
numpy (1.11.0)
pathlib2 (2.1.0)
pexpect (4.0.1)
pickleshare (0.7.2)
pip (8.1.1)
protobuf (2.6.1)
psutil (4.1.0)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pyOpenSSL (16.0.0)
pyparsing (2.1.1)
PySide (1.2.4)
Python-contrib-nbextensions (alpha)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
pytz (2016.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
pyzmq (15.2.0)
qtconsole (4.2.1)
setuptools (21.0.0)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.10.0)
terminado (0.6)
tornado (4.3)
traitlets (4.2.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
widgetsnbextension (1.2.2)
```